# Unable to add trailing /

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to setting up `.htaccess` file and I would appreciate your help in this problem.

I am unable to add trailing `/` to all URLs of my website. I have tried most of the answers on StackOverflow and also this article, but it just didnt work for me, either the styles broke and no `/` was added or just no `/` was added while trying these solutions.

Probably there is some conflict in the rules?

Here is what my `.htaccess` looks like right now:

```
# do not allow anyone else to read your .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

# forbid viewing of directories
Options All -Indexes

# hide this list of files from being seen when listing a directory
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# disable the server signature- helps with preformance
ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# specific rule to show 1 URL but other URL is active
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1.html [L]

# hide /index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# add trailing /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !http://example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to add trailing `/` to all URLs except `http://example.com` (I am higing the default `/index`).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last doesn't look right and besides your rules are in wrong order. Try this code:

```
# do not allow anyone else to read your .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

# forbid viewing of directories
Options All -Indexes

# hide this list of files from being seen when listing a directory
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# disable the server signature- helps with preformance
ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide /index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

# add trailing /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# specific rule to show 1 URL but other URL is active
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Its working, but only after refreshing everytime I open a new page. It is not loading the content after refresh for some pages because it is looking for the corresponding file in the server.

Comment: It works now. But the Javascript code doesnt seem to be working. Any idea, why? You can check it out on that link.

Comment: I have fixed the Javascript part to pull data via AJAX. Now the problem is - try clicking some of the links from the nav bar and click back on the logo to come to the homepage. Now there are 2 `/`'s. How do I get rid of that?